# Почему процедура вызывает исключение в операции с плавающей точкой?

Tags: linux, ассемблер, дата, nasm

Пытаюсь получить из unix-времени отдельно секунды, минуты, часы, день, месяц и год, но моя процедура вызывает исключение в операции с плавающей точкой. Помогите исправить. Вот код процедуры

```
section .seconds_to_date

seconds_to_date:

push eax
push ebx
push ecx
push edx

mov ebx, 60 

div ebx ; eax - minutes
mov [seconds], edx ; seconds
div ebx ; hours
mov [minutes], edx ; minutes

mov ebx, 24
div ebx ; eax - days (целое по идее)
mov ebx, 30
div ebx ; eax - month
mov [day], edx 
mov ebx, 12
div ebx ; eax number of years
mov [month], edx
mov ebx, 1970
add eax, ebx ; year
mov [year], eax

pop edx
pop ecx
pop ebx
pop eax
ret
```

Comment: Запускайте под отладчиком и смотрите где исключение. Скорее всего оно относится к чему то другому, потому что тут исключения работы с плавающей точкой быть не может. Кроме того учтите, что алгоритм в любом случае даст не верный результат, потому как не учитывает кучу нюансов. Например вот алгоритмы https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960318/math-to-convert-seconds-since-1970-into-date-and-vice-versa В википедии есть с таблицей корректировки https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SIGFPE`, вопреки названию, обычно посылается не из-за операции с плавающей точкой, а из-за деления на ноль/переполнения при целочисленном делении. В данном случае здесь второе. И большинство оболочек при этом выводят сильно путающее сообщение «Исключение в операции с плавающей точкой». Это старый известный квирк сложившийся по мутным историческим причинам.

С точки зрения x86 инструкция `div` делит 64-битное число в регистрах `edx`:`eax`, а 32-х битное частное помещается в `eax`, а остаток в `ebx`. Если частное не влезает в 32-х битный регистр, то кидается исключение *#DE* (*INT 0*, *Divide Error*, *Ошибка Деления*), собственно оно же кидается и при делении на ноль.

По коду, собственно скорей всего перед вызовом функции ты не инициализируешь `edx` и явно не обнуляешь его при повторном делении. Ну и в довершении ко всему при вычислении дней/месяцев ты какую-то откровенную ерунду творишь.